# Tableview not showing my appended arrays, even if they are not empty

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

My problem is this: I can load everything from firebase I can append it to the different arrays. But I can't get it to show in my tableview. It does not work when I use section, but if I insert a static string into one of my arrays, eg: accidentMessages: String = ["Hu"] , then Hu is visibly in the tableview under the section "accident"
In the console it prints out my messages from firebase so the strings (messages) has to have been appended to my arrays. But for some reason I can't showcase it in the tableview.
Here is the console log of the messages which is fetched from firebase and added into the arrays.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEva.png)

message 1, should be in "help", message 2 should be in threat, message 3 should be in accident. But it doesn't show, it only shows in the console

```
var helpMessage: [String] = []
var threatMessage: [String] = []
var accidentMessage: [String] = ["Hu"]

var sectionMessages: [Int: [String]] = [:]
let sectionTitle = ["Help:", "Threat:", "Accident"]


sectionMessages = [0: helpMessage, 1: threatMessage, 2: accidentMessage]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitle.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (sectionMessages[section]?.count)!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    let image = UIImageView(image: sectionImages[section])
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 35, height: 35)
    view.addSubview(image)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = sectionTitle[section]
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 5, width: 100, height: 35)
    view.addSubview(label)

    return view

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = sectionMessages[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]

return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sectionMessages` contains copies of the 3 arrays, using whatever values those arrays had at the time that you assigned the value of `sectionMessages`.

If you need to modify those arrays after initializing `sectionMessages`, then you need to modify them in `sectionMessages` directly, rather than modifying the original arrays.

Or you could just ditch `sectionMessages` and instead use something like

```
func messages(for section: Int) -> [String] {
    switch section {
    case 0: return helpMessage
    case 1: return threatMessage
    case 2: return accidentMessage
    default: return []
}
```

Comment: Well here's my git: https://github.com/Lukayne/Pushitt/blob/master/SkolprojektNr2/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thank you! You made it work, I just had to add "sectionMessages = [0: helpMessage, 1: threatMessage, 2: accidentMessage]" into one of my observer methods.